# Как лучше реализовать изменяемую "карту кузова" автомобиля?

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в Android, делаю приложение для проверки автомобилей, требуется реализовать "карту кузова" (пример на фото), чтобы обозначать ремонтированные детали кузова определённым цветом, накладывая поверх каждой детали значения измерений лакокрасочного покрытия. По итогу эта карта будет использоваться в PDF отчёте.

Пример карты (без значений измерений):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моём представлении, нужно создать общую, пустую карту и отельные, прозрачные изображения, с конкретными деталями нужного цвета. По итогу соединять слои вместе и формировать готовое изображение, как ставить цифры в нужные места пока не придумал...

Подскажите, может есть лучший вариант реализации? И как лучше реализовать наложение значений измерений?

Приложение будет использоваться на смартфонах и планшетах

Comment: Раз будет экспорт в PDF то нужна общая процедура прорисовки, а значит (но хозяин барин) для отображения лучше использовать "Custom View" с вытекающей возней позиционирования/масштабирования. Если важен черный контур, то делаем 2 изображения - низ для заливки, а верх для черного контура. Заливать можно просто используя ColorFilter. Если черный контур не важен (будет использоваться градация цвета фильтра) то можно обойтись одним слоем (черный контур и белая заливка).